# cpufreq-stats missing

Tags: 14.04, cpufreq

I'm on kernel `3.16.0-29-lowlatency` on

```
cpu family  : 6
model       : 55
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3540  @ 2.16GHz
```

Unfortunately as the entire `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats` directory is missing so is the `time_in_state` file I'm looking for.

Why is the directory gone? How do I get it back? Are there other means of CPU frequency tracking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not have anything to do with the kernel being a lowlatency flavour. It's intel_pstate cpufreq driver which does not implement statistics. You can disable it via intel_pstate=disable in the kernel command line, but you don't really want to as this will cause more energy usage.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to like this answer: You can choose between **low-latency *or* monitoring.**

### Why?

Well, to be *able* to make a low-latency kernel, *some things are taken out of the kernel..*

That being said, this is open source, so if you *really* want to have CPU frequency tracking in a low-latency kernel, build your own [kernel](https://www.kernel.org/) and `#undefine` a few `#define` statements!

**Hint:** `grep --directories=recurse --ignore-case latency linux-3.18.3/* | grep --ignore-case "#define"`

(Yeah, I only looked through the most recent stable kernel, not yours...)